# Strange character behavior in str_replace_all when used with setNames

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a dataset in which the ages are coded as values 1-9 and I want to swap the definitions in however when I do some of the names are concatenated together. I presume that it has something to do with the "-" character in the definition that I'm trying to do. What do I need to do so that the characters wont cause unexpected returns as this happens in other instances where I try to replace the code with a definition containing "/" as well.

Simple example

```
library(tidyverse)
df.1 <- data.frame(age = round(runif(n = 50, 1, 9),0))
age.pattern <- as.data.frame(cbind(value = 1:9, key = c("0-2",
                                                        "3-9",
                                                        "10-19",
                                                        "20-39",
                                                        "40-59",
                                                        "60-64",
                                                        "65-74",
                                                        "75-84",
                                                        "85+")),
                             stringsAsFactors = F)

df.2 <- df.1 %>%
  mutate(patient_age = str_replace_all(age,
                                setNames(age.pattern$key,
                                         age.pattern$value)))
unique(df.2$patient_age)
[1] "75-84"         "20-385+"       "10-185+"      
[4] "10-185+-85+"   "60-64"         "65-74"        
[7] "0-10-185+-85+" "85+"           "40-585+"
```

Comment: I think you meant the `fixed` vs `regex` case?  By default, it uses regex mode and in regex, the `-` is for range

Comment: @akrun I updated the question to include the output that I see

Comment: You could use `base R` `setNames(age.pattern$key,
                                      age.pattern$value)[as.character(head(df.1$age))]`

Comment: @akrun yeah I suppose that'll work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `str_replace_all` could have issue relating to the `regex` mode.  An easier option is `base R` with a named vector to match and replace

```
df.1$patient_age <- setNames(age.pattern$key, 
                         age.pattern$value)[as.character(df.1$age)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do an exact match here we can use `match` :

```
head(df.1$age, 10)
#[1] 6 3 7 1 4 9 8 3 5 4

head(age.pattern$key[match(df.1$age, age.pattern$value)], 10)
#[1] "60-64" "10-19" "65-74" "0-2" "20-39" "85+" "75-84" "10-19" "40-59" "20-39"
```